# I am trying to replace the first column of a matrix with (0,1,2,3,4,5)

Tags: python, numpy

I used np.zeros((2, 6)) and got an array of:

```
 array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],

  [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

I tried using np.arange(5) but it keeps starting a new code.

I already imported numpy as np

Sorry for my english

Comment: What does "starting a new code" mean?

Comment: Don't worry about English. Let's speak Python. What do you want to get as output?

Comment: What actually comes out?

Comment: If you get an error, please show it.

Comment: Show *exactly* what you did. "I tried arange" means m nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
zeros = np.zeros((2, 6))
zeros[0, :] = np.arange(6)
```